# Views SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause need assistance

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I've tried making a view but i have this problem, I've researched and found out that i needed to separate the views first, but I found it really hard, and i would gladly need some assistance.

Thanks

```js
    SELECT
    coalesce((`rawmat_pallet_ag`.`sheets_pallet` * `rawmat_pallet_ag`.`outs_pallet`),0) AS agpcs,
    coalesce(((`rawmat_pallet`.`no_pallet` * `rawmat_pallet`.`sheets_pallet`) * `rawmat_pallet`.`out_pallet`),0) AS printedpcs,
    coalesce(`rawmat_pcs`.`quantity`,0) AS rawpcs,
    ((coalesce((`rawmat_pallet_ag`.`sheets_pallet` * `rawmat_pallet_ag`.`outs_pallet`),0) + coalesce(((`rawmat_pallet`.`no_pallet` * `rawmat_pallet`.`sheets_pallet`) * `rawmat_pallet`.`out_pallet`),0)) + coalesce(`rawmat_pcs`.`quantity`,0)) AS total,
    rawmaterial.rawmaterial_code AS rawmaterial_code,
    rawmaterial.rawmaterial_desc AS rawmaterial_desc,
    rawmaterial.rawmaterial_id AS raw_id,
    second_view.pending_total,
    COALESCE(total - second_view.pending_total) as available_qty
    FROM
    rawmat_pallet_ag
    RIGHT JOIN rawmaterial
    ON rawmat_pallet_ag.raw_id = rawmaterial.rawmaterial_id 
    LEFT JOIN rawmat_pallet
    ON rawmat_pallet.raw_id = rawmaterial.rawmaterial_id 
    LEFT JOIN rawmat_pcs
    ON rawmat_pcs.raw_id = rawmaterial.rawmaterial_id
    LEFT JOIN (select rawid,sum(first_view.total) as pending_total FROM
    assignedraw LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
    jo_main.item_id,
    sum(jo_main.qty) as total
    FROM
    jo_main
    JOIN so_jo
    ON jo_main.jomain_id = so_jo.jomain_id 
    JOIN somain
    ON so_jo.somain_id = somain.salesorder_id
    where somain.`status` = 1
    group by jo_main.item_id) AS first_view 
    ON assignedraw.itemid = first_view.item_id
    group by assignedraw.rawid) as second_view 
    ON rawmaterial.rawmaterial_id = second_view.rawid
    GROUP BY
    `rawmaterial`.`rawmaterial_id`
    ORDER BY
    raw_id ASC
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not get it: why is it so hard to create other views from the queries in the from clause and reference them in the final view?

Comment: Because I find it somewhat hard, and I dont know the syntax.

Comment: What syntax? You know how to create a view. Other views are referenced as if they were tables.

Comment: You are really overthinking this. Copy the subquery into another window. Create view [yournewview]. Replace subquery  with SELECT FROM [yournewview]

Comment: @JacobH you do not need `select from [yournewview]`, just use `[yournewview]`

Comment: could you guide me step by step?